# Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition is moving 'faster' on axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function that moves a sprite relative to the finger position. I mean that the finger can touch any part of the screen and move the player sprite without moving the sprite to the finger position.

The issue that I have is that it's moving the sprite faster than the actual finger position:

Lets say that i have the finger at (0,0) and the sprite at (10,10); I move the finger 10 units on the X axis and I expect the sprite to move at (20,10), but it's actually moving more units than expected. Let's say it moved to (25,10).

I think it's related to the deltaPosition values. Here's the function (the transform in the arguments is the transform of the sprite that I'm moving):

```
private Vector2 MovePlayerRelativeToFinger(Transform transform)
{
    Vector2 position = transform.position;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;           
        position = new Vector2((touchPosition.x * Time.deltaTime) + transform.position.x, (touchPosition.y * Time.deltaTime) + transform.position.y);
        return position;
    }
    else
    {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition in outer-if statement to

```
Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary
```

TouchPhase.Moved will be true during all the Update when the finger in moved and its deltaPosition will have value right from the point movement is started. So it gets added up into a huge value like, say, your touch started from x and you moved to x + 2 within the next Update. deltaPosition will be 2 during this Update. And if you have moved to x + 5 within the next Update, deltaPosition will be 5 instead of 3 as you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the Stationary just activates if my finger stays on a position. What I'm looking for is for the sprite to mimic the finger movement regardless of the position of the finger in the screen. It does it but if you keep moving the finger the sprite starts to get an offset. i.e I start the touch right on top of the sprite (for testing) and if I keep moving around the sprite starts getting an offset from my finger, I can see the sprite on top of the finger or back from the finger (it depends on the movement). That's how I know my function is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If things have to be that accurate, try this

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0 &&Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
    newDelta = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition - oldDelta;
    position = new Vector2((newDelta.x * Time.deltaTime) + transform.position.x, (newDelta.y * Time.deltaTime) + transform.position.y);
    olDelta += Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition
    return position;
}
```

Initialize oldDelta to 0

Comment: Hi, I was testing your solution. It's a better result than mine but still getting some strange offset. I've tested both yours and mine and noticed that if I swipe faster I get the offset (on both methods). I think it's related to the deltaPosition getting more 'force'(?) relative to the swipe speed?. Also, I've multiplied by 2 the deltaPosition on your solution as I was getting to half of the screen. Still thank you. I think I'm getting closer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I'm not sure why you are including the time there. Or maybe you are missing the transform to world space? Does this work:

```
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        return (transform.position + (Vector3)((1.0f/100) * Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition));
    }
    else
    {
        return transform.position;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, just tried this one too and the sprite jiggled on a corner of the screen. Also, I'm not using ScreenToWorldPoint because the sprite is a child of the Camera and the camera is moving to the right. If I use it, the positions that I get are relative to the world (which start to increse positively on the X axis) and not relative to the screen.

Comment: Are you saving the returned position between the calls and are you calling this function every Update() ? Is it very complex or could you include how you are using the function?

Comment: I tried the updated snippet in a very simple scene with just a cube in the middle and a script attached to it that calls this code every update, and it worked perfectly when I scaled the 1/100 accurately. If you are moving your character somewhere else in the code, that could be causing problems, maybe?